# How to get validation error name for specific model.attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to map error names from attribute validations, and I don't know if it's possible.

I'm trying to automatize translating applications. If an email attribute has validations for presence and format I would like to get names of errors, like: `[:blank, :taken, :invalid]`

I googled and managed to get types of validations with:

```
User.validators_on(:email).map{|v| v.kind}
 => [:presence, :uniqueness, :format]
```

but that is as far as I got.

Comment: Could you create an object in an invalid state and look at the error messages?

Comment: Maybe I could by creating an instance and check for errors after `valid?` but that wouldn't be automated then. I would have to write code for every separate model because format validation wouldn't trigger due to allow_blank: true option.

Comment: Could you create your own map e.g. `{ presence: :blank, ... }` etc. Since you know these are static (i18n aside).

Comment: That is my last resort if there is no other way. Sometimes I add my custom validations and name errors myself. If I could manage to find a way for it to work like I described it wouldn't need my further interventions.

Comment: The error names are added during validation and it's entirely up to the validator which error names or how many are used. For example, the `LengthValidator` might add `:wrong_length`, `:too_short` or `:too_long`. The model isn't aware of these messages and they aren't available before an actual validation occured.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I would have to take a different approach then.

Comment: You could pass a custom message to every validation to get consistent messages, or maybe override with i18n.